# postgresql string_to_array - get the last and one before last elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a long string contained of int,int,float,float * many and I need to get the last two floats.

> 100,140,14.123,15.123,200,240,16.124,17.123

I'm using string_to_array to get element 3 & 4 (first two floats) but I also need a way to get the last two floats (places 7 & 8 in this example).

Comment: I did it a in two iterations, first added a column of the array length:
> UPDATE table SET array_length = array_length(string_to_array(column_to_array,','), 1);

than:
> SELECT (string_to_array(column_to_array,','))[array_length -1], (string_to_array(column_to_array,','))[array_length] FROM table

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing the data like that? Never ever store comma separated values in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_fields(anyarray, int)
RETURNS anyarray LANGUAGE sql AS $$
  SELECT ($1)[array_upper($1,1) - $2 + 1: array_upper($1,1)];
$$;

postgres=# select last_fields(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5], 2);
 last_fields 
─────────────
 {4,5}
(1 row)
```